# Given a value how can I know in which columns it is present?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a huge data frame with 4000 columns, and I need to look if a value exist in one or more columns (I need the name of columns), how can I index the number of columns and the column names in pandas? So far I tried to apply this idea:

```
df.index[df.columns] == 'my_val'].tolist()
```

However this is just returning me boolean values, any dea of how to return the names of the columns where the value lives in?

Comment: You have too many closing brackets. Which one is it?

Comment: `(df == val).any(axis=1)` or so should do it?

Comment: I also tried that one @MadPhysicist

Comment: And what result did you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think need:

```
cols = df.columns[(df == 'my_val').any()]
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'F':list('aaabbb')})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  a  4  7  1  5  a
1  b  5  8  3  3  a
2  c  4  9  5  6  a
3  d  5  4  7  9  b
4  e  5  2  1  2  b
5  f  4  3  0  4  b

cols = df.columns[(df == 'a').any()]
print (cols)
Index(['A', 'F'], dtype='object')
```

**Explanation**:

First compare by value all DataFrame:

```
print (df == 'a')
       A      B      C      D      E      F
0   True  False  False  False  False   True
1  False  False  False  False  False   True
2  False  False  False  False  False   True
3  False  False  False  False  False  False
4  False  False  False  False  False  False
5  False  False  False  False  False  False
```

Then filter at least one `True` per row by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
print ((df == 'a').any())
A     True
B    False
C    False
D    False
E    False
F     True
dtype: bool
```

Last filter `df.columns` by boolean mask:

```
print (df.columns[(df == 'a').any()])
Index(['A', 'F'], dtype='object')
```